# cloudsql databases with django on 'new' flexible google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm building a django (1.9) app using cloudsql and a 'new' flexible environment. I have this same error:
[Django on Google AppEngine with CloudSQL: How to connect database (Error 2002, Can't connect to local MySQL server..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843817/django-on-google-appengine-with-cloudsql-how-to-connect-database-error-2002-c)

However, in that thread, they refer to docs which are older and explain to put the database key ,`HOST`, in the format:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'HOST': '/cloudsql/myapp-test01:myapp-db-test01',
      'NAME': 'test01',
      'USER': 'test01',
    }
```

Whereas in the [documentation for running django on the 'flexible' environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment), it is explained to open your database to the world (0.0.0.0/0) and use the format:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<your-database-name>',
        'USER': '<your-database-user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<your-database-password>',
        'HOST': '<your-database-host>',
        'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
```

Where  is presumably the IP address given by CloudSQL.

Please see the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

Note the 'Flexible Environment' which seems to be distinctly different (but I don't know why).

I'm writing, because I when I change from IP address format to `/cloudsq/...` format I get the error

> OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/desgn-test-01:db-test-01' (2)")

Any advice is *highly* appreciated. It seems impossible that google really expects us to leave databases open to `0.0.0.0`, and in the docs they even say it is only for testing but provide no further information.

I should also mention, I'm using two databases in my django config and the 'default' one is a sqlite db (this part of the site is working fine). I get the error when I try to connect to my app that is using the cloud sql parameter. This ONLY happens when deployed, locally everything works perfect.

Comment: first gen or second gen instance? first gen are not supported from app engine flex & for 2nd gen you need to include the region in the connection string (i recommend copy/pasting the "instance connection name" from Cloud Console)

Comment: It is a second gen instance.. that's what I mean by 'new'... sorry, bit new to GAE. I have exactly as you suggested, copy/pasted 'instance connection name', but to no avail... (that is actually how it was as well).

Comment: Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/app-engine-connect#gaev2-csqlv2. Please follow the steps there and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you. This seems an important piece of information and has resolved my issue!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, can you post an answer with your configuration so that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a PR for the documentation on github, but the key changes that were required in order for me to change my `DEBUG` flag from `True` to `False` are described below.

Be aware, that it seems once you change the `DEBUG` flag, GAE requires that your Cloud SQL database uses the `/cloudsql/` socket connection.

Also, I missed the very critical piece of information regarding the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, which should include `.appspot.com`

#### Production

Once you are ready to serve your content in production, there are several
changes required for the configuration. Most notable changes are:

- Add ".appspot.com" to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`
- Change the `DEBUG` variable to `False` in your settings.py file.
- If you are using a Cloud SQL database
  instance, in order to change from `DEBUG = True`
  to `DEBUG = False` you will need to properly configure the database. See 
  instructions
  [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/app-engine-connect#gaev2-csqlv2) and be
  sure to change your `app.yaml` file as well as the `HOST` key in your
  `DATABASES` object.

Comment: Thanks worked for me, if anyone is in the same scenario, for me was just changing the debug from true to false

Comment: Did you use the following suggestion from Google Cloud Documents to achive this ? beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:<PORT>  from https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#gaev2-csqlv2